# Datepicker information to URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

For those unfamiliar with the bootstrap datepicker, here's a [link](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) to it as well as some examples.

What I'm trying to do is make it so that, once the person clicks a date, it adds that date to the URL and redirects them there.

So for example, if they click the date `September 8, 2013`, it would redirect them to `website.com/period.php?time=09-08-2013` or something like that.

HTML:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dp" data-toggle="dropdown" href="period.php?time=THISISWHATIMMISSING" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date=""<?php echo $current_date ?>"">Custom Date <b class="caret"></b></a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#dp').datepicker()
  .on('changeDate', function(e) {
    var year = e.date.getFullYear(),
    _month = e.date.getMonth() + 1,
    month = (_month > 9 ? _month : '0'+_month),
    _day = e.date.getDate(),
    day = (_day > 9 ? _day : '0'+_day);
    $(this).text(month + '-' + day + '-' + year);
});
```

Please help.

Comment: really whats ur problem?

Comment: I've edited the post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(this).text...` use:

```
$('#dp').attr('href', 'period.php?time=' + month + '-' + day + '-' + year);
```

Comment: Is this event fired? For example, if you put `alert()`, will you see it?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is fired.

Comment: Do you have one element with ID 'dp' on page or several?

Comment: It is not possible :) But it still happens :( Please provide a jsFiddle in this case.